# Is there a way to build persistence in soapui or any similar software?

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

yeah so, our application would be connecting to not yet existing services. We were given WSDLs for those services and we mocked them in soapiu. Is there a way to build rudimentary persistence in soapui or any similar software so that we could have some functionality without actually building the service ourselves?

I've researched on datasinks and datasources for soapui but it seems it only works for testsuites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You build your mockservice, and use enough scripting and datagens to make it seem like the real deal.  Leave it running on someone's PC, or let each developer or team have their own instance to hit.

Then you just send your requests, and SoapUI returns the response. In some cases, a canned response is good enough. In other cases, you may need to pick a response based on something in the request. For example, suppose my StockQuote service has two responses - a good one with the stock price, and a failure, with "symbol not found".  It's simple to script the mockservice so that it gives a known price for symbol 'AA', makes up a price for 'BB', and returns the "unknown symbol" response for everything else.

Here is the tutorial:
http://www.soapui.org/Service-Mocking/creating-dynamic-mockservices.html